# How do you stop an update on an Xbox One Game?

Tags: xbox-one

I have recently bought an xbox one. I also bought the game Doom for my xbox one. 
After it has installed itself, it wanted to install 58 gigabytes of updates over my network. 
How can I stop it updating, and just play the game, how it was on the disk?

Comment: I thought there was an option to not update the game when it prompts you for the update.  What happens if you try that?

Comment: Somebody else accidentally clicked it, and I can't stop the update

Comment: If all else fails you could pull out the ethernet cord (or cut power to your wifi router) and thus disrupt the internet connection and stop the download.  Then, you can take your time going through the XBox settings to disable internet connectivity entirely, and away you go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop an update:

1. Go to your My games and Apps section on your Xbox
2. Navigate to the Queue section on the left and find the game being updated on the right (Doom in this case).
3. Press the Menu button on your controller and select Cancel.  This will stop the update process.

Source: [Xbox Support Page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-one/store/pause-stop-download), as well as experience.

Note that I am unsure if you will be able to play the game offline.  I'm not sure how physical disc copies of games work, but I believe that in order to play any digitally owned game, they must be kept up to date (I could be wrong).

Answer (score 1):

Don’t try to cancel an update. If you cancel an update that has started, it will delete the whole game and its data. Found out the hard way today.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop a game update for any title, you can pause an update and that's about it. I found it to be a pain myself, I started the update not knowing what size it was and thinking maybe a couple of gigs at most and then seen it was 58gig when my monthly allowance is 50gig lol. I paused it and had to take it to my sisters as she lives in the city and has unlimited allowance and update it there. So all you can do is pause it really but you wont be able to play the game until you do the update. Also I have found the loading times to be much longer since the update to the point were i'am not even arsed playing the game anymore. If I had the option to go back I would just uninstall the game instead of updating tbh. Nice work Bethesda!

Answer (score -1):

For doing exactly what you want, install the game from disc, but try installing it after you have toggled the option "Go offline" in Network.

Comment: As the OP clearly states, however, he already installed the game, but just wants to stop the updating.